# String para KeyValuePair usando LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

Estou recebendo uma string no formato "N1N2S3S4L5L6O7O8X" e preciso que ela seja passada para um `KeyValuePair` ou para um `NameValueCollection`.

Onde a key seja a letra e o numero o value.

```
{ N, 1 }
{ N, 2 }
{ S, 3 }
```

Como fazer isso utilizando LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar LINQ neste tipo de tarefa só vai tornar o código difícil de ler.

Usar um `for` normal me parece uma ideia bem melhor.

```
var lista = new List<KeyValuePair<char, char>>();

for(int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, char>(str[i], str[i + 1]));
}
```

Se quiser insistir no LINQ, pode usar o método `Zip`

```
var lista = str.Zip(str.Skip(1), (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<char, char>(k, v))
               .Where((pair, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

Exemplo completo ([veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/029iTm))

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "N1N2S3S4L5L6O7O8X";

        var lista = SemLinq(str);       

        foreach (var kvp in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key} Value: {kvp.Value}");
        }

        var lista2 = ComLinq(str);

        foreach (var kvp in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key} Value: {kvp.Value}");
        }
    }

    public static List<KeyValuePair<char, char>> ComLinq(string str)
    {
        var lista = str.Zip(str.Skip(1), (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<char, char>(k, v)).Where((pair, index) => index % 2 == 0);

        foreach (var kvp in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key} Value: {kvp.Value}");
        }

        return lista.ToList();
    }

    public static List<KeyValuePair<char, char>> SemLinq(string str)
    {
        var lista = new List<KeyValuePair<char, char>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; i += 2)
        {
            lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, char>(str[i], str[i + 1]));
        }

        return lista;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o linq você pode utilizar desta forma:

```
var texto = "N1N2S3S4L5L6O7O8X"; 
var keys = texto.Zip(texto.Skip(1), (Key, Value) => new {Key, Value}).
            Where((pair, index) => index % 2 == 0)
            .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.Key.ToString(), k.Value.ToString()));
```

Veja funcionando no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oLkBri)